# LINQ return non-matching items query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 arrays of different types one is from file and one is from a SQL Database - LINQ to SQL. I'm trying to delete non matching items from my database against items I receive via the file. (I mention this in case there is a more efficient way to do what I'm trying to achieve).

I've drafted up a couple of anonymous arrays to show what I am trying to do:

```
var a = new[] { 
    new { code = "A", subid = 1, test = "dunno" }, new { code = "A", subid = 2, test = "dunno" }, new { code = "A", subid = 3, test = "dunno" },
    new { code = "B", subid = 1, test = "dunno" }, new { code = "B", subid = 2, test = "dunno" }, new { code = "B", subid = 3, test = "dunno" }
};
var c = new[] { 
    new { code = "A", subid = 1 }, new { code = "A", subid = 2 },
    new { code = "B", subid = 1 }, new { code = "B", subid = 2 }
};
```

I need it to return the items that do not match e.g. `new { code = "A", subid = 3 }` and `new { code = "B", subid = 3 }`

```
var b = (from items in a
         where c.Any(d => d.code == items.code && d.subid != items.subid)
         select items);
```

and

```
var b = (from items in a
        where c.Where(d=> d.code == items.code).Any(d => d.subid != items.subid)
        select items);
```

I've tried these but they just seem to return all the items. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

```
var nonMatchingItems = a.Except(c);
```

Full sample:

```
var a = new[] { 
    new { code = "A", subid = 1 }, 
    new { code = "A", subid = 2 }, 
    new { code = "A", subid = 3 },
    new { code = "B", subid = 1 }, 
    new { code = "B", subid = 2 }, 
    new { code = "B", subid = 3 }
};

var c = new[] { 
    new { code = "A", subid = 1 }, 
    new { code = "A", subid = 2 },
    new { code = "B", subid = 1 }, 
    new { code = "B", subid = 2 }
};

foreach(vat item in a.Except(c))
    Console.WriteLine(item);

// { code = A, subid = 3 }
// { code = B, subid = 3 }
```

**UPDATE** (if you have different types, and want to find matches of some set of fields, then use join of sequences, and remove all items from `a` which matched some items in `c`:

```
var matchingItems = from aa in a
                    join cc in c
                        on new { aa.code, aa.subid } equals // properties subset
                           new { cc.code, cc.subid } // same subset 
                    select aa; // select inner item from join       

var nonMatchingItems = a.Except(matchingItems);
```

Comment: The anonymous array in my application does not have matching properties. will this still work?

Comment: Well. You'd need to implement equality operators for the anonymous objects. ;)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky No, they're simply GetHashCode(), which will trip the OP up if they ever have special requirements. Just a note. =)

Comment: @Smithy no, if properties do not match it will not work - sequences should have same type

Comment: @lazyberezovsky no, they are different types also. My apologies for over-simplifying my question :(

Comment: @Smithy you can do except of join to handle different types, see update

Comment: @lazyberezovsky ..turn my arrays into matching anonymous types and then do the .Except() - I was just attempting this in my code. Many thanks :)